# ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier inPL/SQL developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I instaled Oracle and pl/sql developer to manage my databases. but when i want to connect to pl/sql i got the error : `ORA-12154:TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier`

this is my tns.ora :

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = yegane-laptop)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

Comment: eğer allround automations 'ın ürünü olan ise help'in altındaki support info'nun TNS sekmesinde XE'nin karşılığının bulunması gerekiyor.

Comment: What does "tnsping XE" return?

Comment: @OldProgrammer its return :
Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = yegane-laptop)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (20 msec)

Comment: Then your db link works.  can you connect from the command line:  Run sqlpus username/password@XE  (with your username and password)

Comment: @OldProgrammer 
i had run
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Can you see the path that PL/SQL Developer is using to look for the tnsnames.ora file? ([This might help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34687897/266304))

Comment: @AlexPoole I dod not undrestand

Comment: then your problem is with plsql_developer.  Create a system environment variable, TNS_ADMIN=<path to tns folder>

Comment: where and how can i create? @OldProgrammer

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the notepad which you edit your tnsnames.ora file puts '....'(dots) front of each newline. For example:

XE =

..(DESCRIPTION =

....(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = yegane-laptop)(PORT = 1521))

....(CONNECT_DATA =

.....(SERVER = DEDICATED)

......(SERVICE_NAME = XE)

...)

..)

you can check this case with notepad++ selecting 'Show All Charecters'.