# Can't login,ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to go to `PL-SQL Developer`, I enter the name of the database, which is on another computer. The result is the following error.

[image]

I must say right away that this database is registered in the `TNS` file, like other databases.

```
myDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***IP-adress***)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
       (SERVICE_NAME = myDB1)
    )  
  )
```

What is in the computer's `TNS` file is also in the client's file. On the host computer, the database works and starts, but not on the client. The database service has started. As I understand it, the client does not need to create a `listener`, the main thing is that there should be tnsnames.ora. I went through the names and `myDBB1, myDBDB, myDataBase and myDB` and through dots and spaces its `IP address`, but the error did not disappear. Other bases on the client computer work without problems.

Comment: Are you sure PL/SQL Developer is looking at the right file? [The checks in this answer might be helpful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29351187/oracle-pl-sql-developer-cannot-find-my-tnsnames-ora-file#34687897)

Comment: @AlexPoole,Yes, the path is right, I checked now

Comment: In PL/SQL Developer, does it work if you enter the host/port/service directly instead of trying to reference a TNS entry?

Comment: @EJEgyed, not working

Comment: What is the error when you say "not working"? The same as the screenshot? On the host computer, are you able to use SQLPlus using the same TNS entry? Perhaps it is a networking issue?

Comment: Usual diagnostic steps include: tnsping myDB1, ping the hostname returned by tnsping, confirm PL/SQL Dev is using the expected tns location by checking all the details listed in Help > Support Info.